# How to set up two jekyll blogs on Github Pages with the same domain (CNAME)

Tags: github, jekyll, cname

I have two blogs hosted on Github Pages: [travel](https://github.com/alkamid/travel/tree/gh-pages) and [personal](https://github.com/alkamid/alkamid.github.io). The first should appear on http://alkamid.com/travel, the second on http://alkamid.com — and they do, but after pushing the travel CNAME with the same content as the personal one (just one line: `alkamid.com`), I got the following warning from Github:

> The page build completed successfully, but returned the following
>   warning:
>
> CNAME already taken: alkamid.com

I didn't change anything in the settings of my domain provider.

What is the correct way of configuring CNAME for these two blogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `CNAME` from your `/travel` repository. You just need it in your `username.github.io` repository.

**Edit** : This is my point of view about `CNAME` on `github pages` (`ghp`)

The simplest ways to manage custom domain on `ghp` is to set a `CNAME` (pointing to `example.com`) on `username.github.io` and any project repository hosting a `gh-pages` branch can be naturally reached at `example.com/repositoryName`. This is my solution.

But you can always set another `CNAME` on a particular project repository, for a subdomain (`sub1.example.com`) or another domain (`example.org`). This just implies to set a custom DNS. And here it's your choice.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. A short explanation why you can't duplicate CNAMEs and why your solution works would be much appreciated!

Comment: Edited my answer about that.